# Echoing out numbers with duplicates grouped

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called "submission" with the fields "submissionid" and "1adzip".  The field "1adzip" is a ZIP code.

I'm trying to echo out a table that echoes out all of the ZIP codes, and groups duplicates of the same ZIP code.  How can I do this?  The code below is what I tried and it's returning blank results.

```
$query2 = "SELECT submissionid, 1adzip
FROM submission
GROUP BY 1adzip
ORDER BY 1adzip ASC";       


$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

$arr2 = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"commentecho2\">";


while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row2["1adzip"].'</td>';
    echo '<tr>';

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Suggest you test whether `mysql_query` succeeded and output any errors if not: e.g. `$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query probably has an error in it; you might want to escape fields that don't start with an underscore or letters by using the back tick:

```
SELECT submissionid, `1adzip`
FROM submission
GROUP BY `1adzip`
ORDER BY `1adzip` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a summary query (it contains a `GROUP BY` clause), and what you're trying to summarize is a bit confused.

Try this query instead of the one you gave. You may get better results.

```
SELECT count(*) howmany, 1adzip
  FROM submission
 GROUP BY 1adzip
 ORDER BY 1adzip ASC
```